# How to make LinearLayouts clickable

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have a layout which is inherited from LinearLayout, I have this Custom View on MainActivity.

My problem is the ***OnLongTouch*** won't work when I put this ***Custom View*** on an ***Activity*** and it seems my ***custom view*** is ***not clickable***!

**Layout code:**

```
public class AliLayout extends LinearLayout {

    public AliLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);



        if(! isInEditMode()){

            final AliLayout ly2 = this;//(AliLayout)findViewById(R.layout.ali_layout);


            ly2.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    ly2.setTitle("Hello world!");
                    return false;
                }
            });     

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
        LayoutInflater.from(this.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.ali_layout,
                this);

    }


    public void setTitle(String txt) {
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv.setText(txt);
    }

}
```

**inflated xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout1"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="68dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:background="#E0D641"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:longClickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:longClickable="true"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <com.example.component.AliLayout
        android:id="@+id/ali1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp" >
    </com.example.component.AliLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: But why not remove RelativeLayout and use AliLayout directly?

Comment: @MarcoAcierno because that RelativeLayout is a container for a couple of AliLayouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying and failing for hundred times I found the solution to my problem!

Instead of:

```
ly2.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    ly2.setTitle("Hello world!");
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

I should have written:

```
this.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            setTitle("Hello World");
            return true;
        }
    });
```

And I shouldn't have used `android:clickable` and `android:longClickable` for inflated XML(ali_layout.xml):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout1"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="68dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:background="#E0D641"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Finally, the problem solved ...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your layout is not filling the screen at all since you are using wrap_content with no content in it:

switch your layout to

```
 <com.example.component.AliLayout
    android:id="@+id/ali1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp" >
</com.example.component.AliLayout>
```

Comment: I don't think this is a correct answer,
For e.g I had a LinearLayout on MainActivity which had wrap_content for both layout_width and height but the OnTouchListener/OnLongTouchListenenr worked fine!

My problem is, those events won't work when I create a new class which is inherited from LinearLayout.

Comment: wrap_content will work, but in your case, your custom layout does not have anything in it. Therefore, when you set the height to wrap_content, it is technically equal to zero which gives you nothing to click. If you keep it with wrap_content you need to add something into the view for you to have something to click.

Comment: Did you look at xml?
There are two TextViews in the Layout. :)

Comment: Oh. I missed that you were inflating the first xml. I was looking at the MainActivity XML. The only thing I can think that  is happening is that the Inflated view is completely filling out you custom view and when you click it, the Inflated LinearLayout is taking the click as opposed to your custom view. Have you tried adding anything directly into the custom layout in the MainActivity xml and see what happens?

Comment: I think I found what wrong was with my code!

I'll share soon here.

Comment: I posted my answer, take a look if you like.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering the question of title,   you can use two options for xml and code:

Put in the xml:

```
android:clickable="true"
```

Or in .java

```
 yourLinearLayout.setClickable(true);
```

Comment: Have you looked at my codes?
I have set clickable for my Layout!

Answer (score 0):

`layout.setclickble="true"` in XML file and

```
layout.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub     
    }
});
```

Comment: `android:clickble="true"` actually